# Embedding iframe in mobile app , issues with the view-port scaling

Tags: iframe, mobile-website

I have a mobile web application which has the following view-port.

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
```

In one of the pages of our mobile web app, we are embedding another website using an iframe. This web application is not responsive and doesn't have a viewport meta tag in the head.

We wanted the embedded site's view to be without any initial-scale, but unfortunately, it is having an initial scale (may be 1.0) which attached to it. Looks like it's inheriting from the parent frame. Browser is not letting me to zoom out the iframe content. Both the parent and embedded webpage is in the same domain as well.

Below is the generated code from the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- some content -->
<div>
  <div class="iframe-wrapper">
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="url ot the site>
#document
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
   ..
   </head>
  <body>
   ...
   </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would it be possible to have a different viewport for the iframe rather than reusing the one from the parent?